# How to apply __str__ function when printing a list of objects in Python

Tags: python, list, object, printing, string

Well this interactive python console snippet will tell everything:

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'asd'
...
>>> t = Test()
>>> print(t)
asd
>>> l = [Test(), Test(), Test()]
>>> print(l)
[__main__.Test instance at 0x00CBC1E8, __main__.Test instance at 0x00CBC260,
 __main__.Test instance at 0x00CBC238]
```

Basically I would like to get three `asd` string printed when I print the list. I have also tried `pprint` but it gives the same results.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try:

```
class Test:
   def __repr__(self):
       return 'asd'
```

And read this [documentation link](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

Answer (score 13):

The suggestion in other answers to implement `__repr__` is definitely one possibility.  If that's unfeasible for whatever reason (existing type, `__repr__` needed for reasons other than aesthetic, etc), then just do

```
print [str(x) for x in l]
```

or, as some are sure to suggest, `map(str, l)` (just a bit more compact).

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a `__repr__` method:

```
>>> class Test:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'asd'
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'zxcv'

    
>>> [Test(), Test()]
[zxcv, zxcv]
>>> print _
[zxcv, zxcv]
```

Refer to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

> ## `object.__repr__(self)`
>
> Called by the `repr()` built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form `<...some useful description...>` should be returned. The return value must be a string object. If a class defines `__repr__()` but not `__str__()`, then `__repr__()` is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.
>
> This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous.

Comment: From the documentation provided in the answer, it seems that I do not need __str__ definition if __repr__ is used. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Blink_: It depends on what exactly you want.  Using the class I have defined, compare the output of `print Test()` against `print [Test()]`.