# Concatenation of items in list

Tags: python, string, text, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have such a list:

```
['S/M - Black', ' 93094-01']
```

It is the result of:

```
m['value'].split(',')[0:2:]
```

How can I produce such a string from it:

```
'S/M - Black, 93094-01'
```

I have tried:

```
print [i + ', ' + i for i in m['value'].split(', ')[0:2:]]
```

But it gives me:

```
['S/M - Black, S/M - Black', ' 93094-01,  93094-01']
```

Comment: as a side note, just `[:2]` would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the join method:

```
",".join(m['value'].split(', ')[0:2:])
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have seen,

```
[i + ', ' + i for i in m['value'].split(', ')[0:2:]]
```

applies that format to each item in turn. Instead, you want:

```
", ".join(m['value'].split(",")[:2])
```

(note the neater slice, which means "the first two items"). For example:

```
>>> ", ".join(['S/M - Black', ' 93094-01'])
'S/M - Black,  93094-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = ['S/M - Black', ' 93094-01']
string = ','.join(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

The .split function returns a list, read docs here https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

So you can join you're list values by using ','.join(['S/M - Black', ' 93094-01']) as answered earlier on a similar question [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['S/M - Black', ' 93094-01']
str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in list1)
```