# Joining the numbers to form a new number

Tags: python

If I define a function that yields a list of numbers and I want to join those numbers to form a new number what should I do?

For example: if `f(6) == [2, 3, 5]`, I want `235` as result.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I dont know how to join things in list. That's the problem.

Comment: So what research have you done? Had you bothered to search, for example, you might have found http://stackoverflow.com/q/12453580/3001761

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.join` with `for` loop

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
In [75]: int(''.join(str(i) for i in l))
Out[75]: 235
```

Or use simple math:-

```
In [77]: s = 0

In [78]: for x in l:
   ....:     s = s*10 + x
   ....:     

In [79]: s
Out[79]: 235
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number you want to to represent is in base10, you can do:

```
sum([x*10**(len(l)-i-1) for i,x in enumerate(l)])
```

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria You mean the basis? like with hexadecimals? This should work for any length of l.