# Python Concatenate string with all members of a list and display each display result separated by commas

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I'm trying to do something like a "conjugator".

Say I have a list of endings:

```
endings = ['o', 'es', 'e', 'emos', 'eis', 'em']
```

and I have a verb root as a string:

```
root = "com"
```

The way I thought of doing this is:

```
for ending in endings:
    print root + ending
```

which outputs:

```
como
comes
come
comemos
comeis
comem
```

But my desired result is:

```
como, comes, come, comemos, comeis, comem
```

How can I achieve exactly this (and with no quotes around each of the resulting items, and no comma after the last item)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate item in list to strings - python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a list comprehension and [`str.join()`.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) From the documentation:

> `str.join(iterable)`
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the
>   strings in the iterable iterable. The separator between elements is
>   the string providing this method.

```
>>> root = "com"
>>> endings = ['o', 'es', 'e', 'emos', 'eis', 'em']
>>> verbs = [root + ending for ending in endings]
>>> print ", ".join(verbs)
como, comes, come, comemos, comeis, comem
```

Comment: one-liner: `print ", ".join(root + ending for ending in endings)`

Comment: Thanks! I tried using different methods (including those in the question this one is marked as a "possible duplicate" of, but none of them worked; I got either a different output or errors. This works perfect.