# Combining elements of a list in python to a single element

Tags: python, python-3.x

list:

```
['a','b']
```

Expected List:

```
['a,b']
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Can you give us a longer example? There are many ways to do it for the current example. Basically, we want to see whether the list is populated only by strings, or lists of lists with strings, etc.

Comment: So far this looks like a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l2 = [','.join(l)]
```

There's not much point to wrapping this output in a list, though. It'd probably make more sense to just get the string:

```
joined_string = ','.join(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join`

```
>>> l = ['a','b']
>>> [', '.join(l)]
['a, b']
```