# How do I concat a string of chars together from a matrix in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The problem I'm working on is outputting a matrix in a clockwise inwards spiral. My code, right now, does this but the output is a little different than what is expected.

```
matrix = [
  ['a','d','g','e','t','c'],
  ['p','k','h','w','e','f'],
  ['m','j','y','h','b','n'],
  ['e','o','j','n','g','y']
]

def spiralPrint(mat):
  top = 0
  left = 0
  right = len(mat[0])-1
  bot = len(mat)-1

  result = []

  while(True):    
    #TRAVERSE ACROSS TOP ROW
    for j in range(left, right+1, 1):
      result.append(mat[top][j])

    #INC TOP INDEX SO WE DON'T REPEAT
    top += 1         

    #EXIT CONDITION
    if top > bot or left > right:
      break

    #TRAVERSE RIGHTMOST COLUMN
    for i in range(top, bot+1, 1):
      result.append(mat[i][right])             
    right -= 1
    if top > bot or left > right:
      break

    #TRAVERSE BOTTOM ROW
    for k in range(right, left-1, -1):
      result.append(mat[bot][k]) 
    bot -=1        

    if top > bot or left > right:
      break

    #TRAVERSE LEFT COLUMN
    for p in range(bot, top-1, -1):
      result.append(mat[p][left])             
    if top > bot or left > right:
      break
    left += 1

  return result

print(spiralPrint(matrix))
```

The output is supposed to look like: adgetcfnygnjoempk...

My output is: ['a', 'd', 'g', 'e', 't', 'c', 'f', 'n', 'y', 'g', 'n', 'j', 'o', 'e', 'm', 'p', 'k', 'h', 'w', 'e', 'b', 'h', 'y', 'j']

How do I output just the chars without the quotes and commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning `result`, do

```
return ''.join(result)
```

As the name implies, it joins the contents of list `result` into one string. The empty string at the beginning means nothing will be put between successive elements. For more details, see the join section [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

You get a list for `result` rather than a string since you repeatedly `append` to it, which is a list method. (Of course, you also initialized it as the empty list.) You could concatenate and keep `result` a string, but using a list then joining together is actually the recommended way of adding characters to a string. So you hit the Pythonic way perhaps by accident.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be in one line you can use this code

```
import numpy as np
''.join(np.array(matrix).flatten())
Out[101]: 'adgetcpkhwefmjyhbneojngy'
```

if you want to fix your code `print(''.join(spiralPrint(matrix)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use join [(duplicate question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

```
>>> result = ['a', 'd', 'g']
>>> ''.join(result)
'adg'
>>> ' '.join(result)
'a d g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your spiralPrint call into a join:

```
print(''.join(spiralPrint(matrix)))
```

This will create a new string with each value. You could also add a delimiter to the leading string to create delimited output. For example:

```
print('-'.join(spiralPrint(matrix)))
```

gives the output: a-d-g-e-t-c-f-n-y-g-n-j-o-e-m-p-k-h-w-e-b-h-y-j

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are returning the result as a list, what tou expected is a single string,so you just have to join the list into a string.
Instead of return result, do 
return ''.join(result)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning list. In order to make it return the string, you need to join the list. In your case as: `return ''.join(result)`.

---

Also, as per [Python PIP's coding guideline for **Function Names**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names):

> *Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.*

Hence, your function should be `spiral_print()` instead of `spiralPrint()`