# Python permutations of given string

Tags: python, string, permutation

My code is pretty simple. My task is to get every permutation of given string.
Compute number of permutations - that's clear - factorial.

Code

```
s = "aba"
perm = list("".join(string) for string in permutations(s))# all permutations
numberOfPerm = len(perm) #number of permutations
unique = len(list(set(perm))) #number of unique permutations
list.sort(perm) # ascii sorting
format_list = [numberOfPerm, unique]
print("total: {} (unique: {}) ".format(*format_list))
print(perm)
```

Output of this is

```
total: 6 (unique: 3) 
['aab', 'aab', 'aba', 'aba', 'baa', 'baa']
```

The thing is i need it to be like this

```
 total: 6 (unique: 3) aab, aab, aba, aba, baa, baa
```

I bumped on various solutions e.g. `''.join(finalArray)`, but none of them work either in my pycharm or in VPL (virtual programming lab) - traceback errors appear. Thanks for eventual help.

Comment: Don't you think it would be helpful to *post the errors you are receiving?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate item in list to strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("total: {} (unique: {}) {}".format(*format_list, ', '.join(perm))
```

Comment: This solution doesn't pass VPL, but definitely works in pycharm. 

File "Anagram.py", line 10
    print("total: {} (unique: {}) {}".format(*format_list, ', '.join(perm)))
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression

Comment: Try to change `*format_list` with `format_list[0], format_list[1]`

Comment: well seems to be problem with my knowledge of python basics, another kind of failure appeared. I am using `s = str(input())` instead `s = "aba"` and there are two failures in the tests this one

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ana.py", line 4, in <module>
    s = str(input())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'kladno' is not defined`

Comment: ok..it is the problem with VPL... It is prolly using python 2.x instead of 3.x. So thx for your answer..marking as solved