# My program is supposed to output answers into a csv file with a certain format

Tags: python-3.x, csv

This is the code

```
import datetime

mylist = []
today = datetime.date.today()
mylist.append(today)
print(mylist[0])

file = open('Date.txt', 'a')
file.write(mylist)
file.close()
global timestable
global text
def timestable():
    global name
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    global number
    number = int(input("Insert a number you want the 12 times table for: "))
    global multiply
    for multiply in range(1,13):
        print(number,"x",multiply,"=",number*multiply)
        text()

def text():
    file=open("list.csv","a")
    file.write("The date is," + today + "\nTimestables are:\n" + number + "x" + multiply + "=" + number*multiply + "\nYour name is, " + name)
    file.close()
    text()
timestable()
```

The problem is that nothing is being outputted into the file and its supposed to be outputted with a certain format also.

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Code\Lesson Task Code.py", line 9, in <module>
    file.write(mylist)
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Comment: The error tells you what to do! Fastest way is `file.write(str(mylist))` or you use `join` to write a nice output (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Comment: the python [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) may also come in handy...

Comment: "supposed to be outputted with a certain format".  What's the format?  What you are writing in `text()` is nothing like a CSV format, plus it will infinitely recurse and crash once you fix your current error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `datetime.date.today()` you probably want to tryout `time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`:

```
from time import strftime

today = strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(today)

with open('Date.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(today+"\n")
```