# Remove commas in list and make a sentence with list items

Tags: python, python-2.7

So basically I have a list with 4 items.

```
list = ['My', 'name', 'is', 'mike']
```

What I want to do is to remove the commas that split the items and make one string. The removed commas should be replaced with space. What I have seen so far is the replace method for string's. I have been wondering if there is something similar for lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
>>> ' '.join(list)
'My name is mike'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join the items of your list using a whitespace `' '` as the separator

```
list = ['My', 'name', 'is', 'mike']
oneString = ' '.join(list)
```

This question has already been asked and answered in more detail here [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings) .