# Bulk renaming files with Python

Tags: python, directory

I have multiple `files` in various folders that look like this:

```
cat - dog - bark.docx
```

I want to bulk rename the files so that the string before the first hyphen is moved to the end of the filename:

```
dog - bark - cat.docx
```

Here’s what I’ve got so far:

```
import os
path = input(‘Copy and paste the location of the files.’)
for filename in os.listdir(path):
  filename_without_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
  extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
  str_to_move = filename.split('-')[0]
  new_filename = filename_without_ext.split('-')[1:] + ' - '+ str_to_move + extension
  os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, new_filename))
```

When I run the code it brings up the error message

```
‘TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list’. I’d be very grateful if someone could tell me what I’m doing wrong.
```

I’m new to coding and Python (as you can probably tell) so go easy on me.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: My guess would be filename_without_ext.split('-')[1:] is returning a list not a single string even if its just a list of 1 element.

Comment: You have file names with spaces in them, and you are renaming them in some way what that *doesn't even remove the spaces*? Needs more [detox](http://detox.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate a list with a string which does not work. Try replacing:

```
new_filename = filename_without_ext.split('-')[1:] + ' - '+ str_to_move + extension
```

with

```
new_filename = '-'.join(filename_without_ext.split('-')[1:]) + '-' + str_to_move + extension
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path = input(‘Copy and paste the location of the files.’)
for filename in os.listdir(path):
  filename_without_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
  extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
  parts_of_filename = filename_without_ext.split(' - ')
  new_filename = parts_of_filename[1] + ' - '+ parts_of_filename[2] + ' - ' + parts_of_filename[0] + extension
  os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, new_filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
new_filename = filename_without_ext.split('-')[1:] + ' - '+ str_to_move + extension
```

You're trying to concatenate a string to a list. The assumption you're making is that each element of the list would be added together before your next statement. The code is ambiguous as you could either want that or you could want to add your substring to each element of the list.

You want to use `join` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings) said.

So:

```
'-'.join(filename_without_ext.split('-')[1:])
```

Though you still have the leading space on your first entry to worry about. So you might want to split by `' - '` instead.

Comment: Thanks! This explanation is very helpful.

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful :)