# why Storing multiple variables is creating a tuple

Tags: python

Hi i am writing a code but unfortunately when i try to store multiple variables from a list or tuple into a new variable it just makes a new tuple

```
content=['2.0', 'Banana']
newli = content[0],'\t',content[1]
print(newli)
```

It should be printing like a string but it is printing as a tuple in round brackets. I need this tab spacing in between these two variables. Any help would be really appreciated.

by doing `content[0]+'\t'+content[1]` the tab space is not working

Actually what i wanted to achieve it so i can call this variable anywhere without using the manual print command everywhere and also to write in a file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Comment: Do consider using `join` instead as the last comment says.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the commas with + i.e.

```
newli = content[0] + '\t' + content[1]
```

Comment: by doing this the tab space is not coming

Comment: When I run it  the tab is there.

Comment: Its strange when i check on repl.it space it coming but not in my pycharm

Comment: Your pycharm console might be rendering the tab as 0 spaces, you could replace `'\t'` with `4*' '` to make sure it works on all consoles.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using string concatenation, but creating a tuple. You use `,` separation to create a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm). You need to use `+` to [concatenate](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python) strings.

```
content=['2.0', 'Banana']
newli = content[0] + '\t' + content[1]
print(newli)
```

Comment: by doing this the tab space is not coming

Answer (score 1):

`newli` is a tuple, since you're grouping values with a comma.

You should make it a string by doing this:

```
content=['2.0', 'Banana']
newli = content[0] + '\t' + content[1]
print(newli)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior:

`a = 'first', '\t', 'second'` creates a tuple containing `'first'`, and tab and `'second'`
`a = 'first',` creates a tuple containing `'first'`; it is the comma that makes the tuple.

If you want to concatenate the values as a string, you could do like this:

`a = 'first' + '\t' + 'second'`

or like this, using `f-strings`:

```
f = 'first'
m = '\t'
s = 'second'
a = f'{f}{m}{s}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are asking for newli to store items as a tuple.
Use string concatenation if you want to store them as a string

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's because you are putting comas between the strings. In python string concatenation is done with the `+` operator.

Try changing your code to:

```
content=['2.0', 'Banana']
newli = content[0] + '\t' + content[1]
print(newli)
```

Comment: by doing this the tab space is not coming

Answer (score 0):

In Python values that are separated by comma (`,`) produces a tuple of that values.
Like:

```
a=10
b=5
total_data = a,b
print(total_data) #this will produce a tuple (10, 5)
```

To get output as `string` you need to use `+` operator:

```
content=['2.0', 'Banana']
newli = content[0]+'\t'+content[1]
print(newli) #output: 2.0   Banana
```

Also you can use `join` function to get your expected output. Like:

```
content=['2.0', 'Banana']
newli = content[0],content[1]
print("\t".join(newli)) #output: 2.0   Banana
```