# Removing stopwords that begin a sentence with NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I'm attempting to remove all the stop words from text input.  The code below removes all the stop words, except one that begin a sentence.

How do I remove those words?

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords_nltk_en = set(stopwords.words('english'))

from string import punctuation
exclude_punctuation = set(punctuation)

stoplist_combined = set.union(stopwords_nltk_en, exclude_punctuation)

def normalized_text(text):
   lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()
   stopwords_punctuations_free = ' '.join([i for i in text.lower().split() if i not in stoplist_combined])
   normalized = ' '.join(lemma.lemmatize(word) for word in stopwords_punctuations_free.split())
return normalized


sentence = [['The birds are always in their house.'], ['In the hills the birds nest.']]

for item in sentence:
  print (normalized_text(str(item)))

OUTPUT: 
   the bird always house 
   in hill bird nest
```

Comment: Please don't clean your text in this manner, take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk . You're iterating through the text multiple times for no good reason.

Comment: I modified some of the code as you suggested.

Comment: You didn't read the full kernel ;P Lemmatization needs POS tags.

Comment: I did read the page and did attempted the POS tag item, but I couldn't get the output to work as I wanted.  The output was in a list, but I wanted a string like my other code was outputting.   Suggestions are welcome to get the same output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings ;P

Comment: thanks for the link.  After more testing I noted that the lemmatize piece was removing items that I needed to analyze. I plan to use my output in some type of text classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is this line of code:

```
print (normalized_text(str(item)))
```

If you try to print `str(item)` for the first element of your `sentence` list, you'll get:

```
['The birds are always in their house.']
```

which, then, lowered and split becomes:

```
["['the", 'birds', 'are', 'always', 'in', 'their', "house.']"]
```

As you can see, the first element is `['the` which does not match the stop word `the`.

**Solution:** Use `''.join(item)` to convert item to `str`

---

**Edit after comment**

Inside the text string there are still some apices `'`. To solve, call the `normalized` as:

```
for item in sentence:
    print (normalized_text(item))
```

Then, import the regex module with `import re` and change:

```
text.lower().split()
```

with:

```
re.split('\'| ', ''.join(text).lower())
```

Comment: You are correct, this modification solved my issue in my example code, but I'm still having an issue in the production piece.

Comment: In the production code, I'm reading in a text file, which contains lines :          
'The birds are always in their house',
'In the hills the birds nest',
'No birds are in their homes', 
etc...,

Comment: This is the output of a single line: ["'in", 'the', 'hills', 'the', 'birds', 'nest'"] using  with open('summaries.txt', 'r') as input:                                                             
 lines = input.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        test = ''.join(line)
        print (test.lower().split())

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I can't understand which problem you're facing now

Comment: look at the output of this:   sentence = [["'The birds are always in their house'"], ["'In the hills the birds nest'"]]

Comment: Thanks, that worked.   Is there a way to use both checks in my code?

Comment: Which checks do you refer to?

Comment: Disregard it's working on all the text items that I have tried.  THANKS!!