# convert 2d integer Array to a string separated by commas python

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7

i have this array

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

i would like to convert it in to
 a string like this

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

i have tried doing the below code but it didnt do what i wanted to

```
 A = str(A).strip('[]')
```

output i get for this is

```
1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9
```

*note*: i would like to do this without any external libraries

so basically converting 2d array into strings separated by commas

Comment: First [flatten the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists), then convert the numbers to string, and finally [use `str.join`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings). In this case, it would be: `", ".join([str(item) for sublist in A for item in sublist])`. I think this should be a dupe of the two posts I linked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to do this is @pault's suggestion (see comments). Flatten your list, and join with a comma:

```
>>> ', '.join([str(i) for x in A for i in x])
'1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9'
```

But to address the issue with your code, `str.strip` only removes the trailing and leading characters, which is why you end up with your brackets still in the middle. You *could* chain two `replace`s together instead (but `join`ing a flattened list is better):

```
>>> str(A).replace('[','').replace(']','')
'1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9'
```