# Finding a specific sequential pattern

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Id  Seq Event
1     2    A 
1     3    B 
1     5    c 
1     6    A 
2     1    A 
2     2    B 
2     4    A 
2     6    B
```

I want to find how many times a specific pattern appears. Let's say "AB" . The output should be.

```
Id  Pattern_Count
1    1
2    2
```

I tried using Event + Event.shift() and searching for the specific pattern. It's a tedious task when I have to search for a longer pattern like "ABCDE" and I don't want to shift it 4 times. Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `groupby`, `agg`, and `str.count`:

```
(df.groupby('Id')['Event']
   .agg(''.join)
   .str.count('AB')
   .reset_index(name='Pattern_Count'))

   Id  Pattern_Count
0   1              1
1   2              2
```

Note that `str.count` will work for simple substring matches only, regex patterns are not supported directly.

Comment: I've been studying your answer. It amazes me that so many things can be strung together in this dense fashion. I would not have thought of using .join as a function to .agg. It does not show up in the documentation I have read. How did you know you could use that in .agg?  I tried dir(groupby.agg) to list all functions, but it did not work.

Comment: @R.Wayne You can pass any function to agg, as long as it results in a single, aggregated value. In this case, I used `str.join`. See [this post on string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings). `agg(''.join)` can also be specified as `agg(lambda x: ''.join(x))` but is more verbose and less performant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` to isolate your groups then concatenate your strings with `sum` to count the occurrences of your substring.

```
result = df.groupby('Id')['Event'].sum().str.count('AB')
```

Comment: concatenating strings with sum is not very efficient since strings are immutable.

Comment: Good point. Seemed more intuitive to use `sum`, but `join` should be the faster approach.