# Is there any function in python list to convert comma seperated values to a single element?

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for converting a list of strings separated by comma to a single element like so:

```
my_list=['A','B','B','C','C','A']
```

I want the output to be:

```
my_list=['ABBCCA']
```

Comment: Why not `''.join`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
my_list = ["".join(my_list)]
print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
['ABBCCA']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> my_list= ['A','B','B','C','C','A']
>>> "".join(my_list)
'ABBCCA'
```

So in your case, enclose it in a list:

```
>>> ["".join(my_list)]
['ABBCCA']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can concat str by `join`:

```
my_list = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A']
print(''.join(my_list))   # 'ABBCCA'
```

if you mean split comma in one string, like:

```
s = 'A,B,B,C,C,A'
print(''.join(s.split(',')))   # 'ABBCCA'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop too:

```py
str=''
for i in my_list:
     str+=i
print(str)
```