# Flattening a dictionary

Tags: python

In this function, I am trying to create a list which includes the keys of a dictionary multiplied by the value they are mapped to, value being a non-negative integer. My code gives me what I am looking for but treats every character of the keys(which are strings) as individual and not as one string, i.e. {'APPLE': 2} --> ['A', 'P', 'P', 'L', 'E', 'A', 'P', 'P', 'L', 'E'] and not 
['APPLE', 'APPLE']
Here is my code:

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    flattened_dict = []
    for key in d:
        flattened_dict += flatten_lists(key)*d[key]
    return flattened_dict
```

Thank you for all help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Comment: list('APPLE' * 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help, instead of multiplying, which would concatenate the string, i iterated over the number:

```
flattenset = {'APPLE': 2, 'WHAT': 3}
flattenlist = []
for item in flattenset:
  for x in range(flattenset[item]):
    flattenlist.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to walk through all dictionary key-value pairs and append each key `value` times to the new list. `dict.items()` is a nice way to make this a bit more concise too.

```
flattened_list = []

for k,v in d.items():
    for _ in range(v):
        flattened_list.append(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently having the key on a word level, you need to flatten the keys to character level first. One way to achieve that is to create a new dictionary/hashtable that counts the occurrence of each character in the word, then use your current code on that new dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, then this code will put the `keys` of your dicionary `value` times into a list.

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    flattened_dict = []
    for key, value in d.items():
        flattened_dict.extend([key for _ in range(value)])
    return flattened_dict


print(flatten_dict({"Apple": 2,
                    "Pear": 3,
                    "Nuts": 0}))
```

Outputs:
`['Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear']`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single line answer using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
a = {'APPLE':2, "Orange": 3}

# extract the key and values from a.items() and then repeat it 'n' times
output = [key for key, value in a.items() for n in range(value)]

output
```

This returns:

```
['APPLE', 'APPLE', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange']
```

To break down the comprehension:
This extracts each key, value pair from the dictionary and returns the key

```
key for key, value in a.items()
```

And then we repeat the key by value times

```
for n in range(value)
```

Note: `n` is not really used and can even be replaced by `_` to indicate a throw away value.