# Python converts from strings of word into list of word

Tags: python

I am new to Python and i have a problem of converting the strings of words into a list of word and my string will be downward like this.

- Hello 1
- Hello 2
- Hello 3

I want to convert to a list example: List=['Hello 1','Hello 2','Hello 3']
List[0]='Hello 1'
...
How to do this? any help will appreciate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings

Comment: the string will be like all Hellos will be in new line 
or (Hello 1 , Hello 2 , Hello 3 ...)
or (Hello 1  Hello 2  Hello 3 ...)

Comment: the strings are like Hello 1 \n Hello 2 \n Hello 3

Answer (score 3):

use split function:

```
hello_str = "hello1 hello2 hello3"
hello_list = hello_str.split()
```

this will result

```
['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
st="Hello 1 \n Hello 2 \n Hello 3"
ArrStr=st.split("\n")
print(ArrStr)
```