# Is there a more elegant way to write a list join function in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, join

I'm using Python 3.7.  I want to turn a list of elements into a string by concatenating each element and inserting a string in between them.  So if my list consists of

```
"a", "b", "c"
```

I would like the result to be

```
"a-b-c"
```

I can't find a single Python function to do this.  Does one exist?  I have resorted to writing this

```
def concatenate_list_data(list):
    result= ''
    for element in list:
        result += "-"
        result += element
    return result
```

but figure there is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join` is exactly for you:

`res = '-'.join(my_list)` where `my_list` is your iterable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
result = '-'.join(mylist)
```