# How to print from the list dynamically

Tags: python, list

l = ['a','b']

Output > `the elements in list are '%a','%b'`

l = ['a','b','c']

Output > `the elements in list are '%a','%b','%c'`

Like for any number of elements we need to add `the elements in the list are` and also with express with percentage `%`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `f-strings` and `join`.

```
sub_str = ", ".join(f"'%{e}'" for e in l)
print(f"the elements in the list are {sub_str}")
```