# result = [ch for ch in string if (ch != ' ')]; result = str(result); print(result); prints list, not string

Tags: python

I need to convert 'a b c' to 'abc' so made this code:

```
string = 'a b c'

result = [ch for ch in string if (ch != ' ')]
print(type(result))

result = str(result)
print(type(result))

print(result)
```

result of this code is expected as:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
'abc'
```

but result is as:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

why result is printed list? this makes faults in other part of my code.

Comment: Unlike how `list(thing)` means "iterate over `thing` and put the elements in a list" and `tuple(thing)` means "iterate over `thing` and put the elements in a tuple", `str(thing)` doesn't mean "iterate over `thing` and put the elements in a string". You need to use `''.join(thing)` for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str()` on a list does not magically turn said list into a no delimiter string. When you do
`str(['a', 'b', 'c'])` - what you actually get is `'['a', 'b', 'c']'`, which is indeed a string.

If you'd like the result to be `'abc'` please, use [`.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```py
''.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Output-

```py
'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `result = [ch for ch in string if (ch != ' ')]` you eliminate spaces and save the chars into list. But to have string again, you need to join them:

```
string = 'a b c'

result = [ch for ch in string if (ch != ' ')]

s = "".join(result)

print(s)  # abc
```

Here is the related doc [page.](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/join.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
string = 'a b c'
print(string.replace(' ' ,''))
```

Output :

```
abc
```

Comment: While that is a more direct method to get from A to B, it doesn't answer OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a list cause you are using list comprehension.
here I have split the string into spaces using the string method split
which returns a list
I have printed the type of the list and type of element in the list
and joined them back using the string method join

```
string = 'a b c'

string = string.split(' ')
print(type(string))
print(type(string[0]))

print("".join(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

The line of code

```
result = [ch for ch in string if (ch != ' ')]
```

is an example of a *list comprehension* in Python.

The `for` loop within this list takes each value from the string, one at a time, and places it into the list - this is why the list `['a', 'b', 'c']` appears in your code.

To obtain a string without spaces from a string with spaces:

```
string = 'a b c'
# obtain characters from the string that are not spaces
result = [ch for ch in string if (ch != ' ')]
# put the string back together without spaces
string_no_spaces = ''.join(result)
>>>'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `str(['a', 'b', 'c'])` actually do is, `str` calls up the [`__str__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) of the given object (which is `list` now) to its constructor which makes: `'['a', 'b', 'c']'` string.

> why result is printed list? this makes faults in other part of my code.

What `print` does before dumping is `str('['a', 'b', 'c']')`, which effectively does nothing here, printing it just strips out `'` *making* you think that it's a list.