# How to separate items in a list with string in python3.x?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of single character strings:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

I need to print the items in the list, separated with `->` like so:

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also be sure to search for existing answers (like [concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)) before posting a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use the `join()`

```py
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
' -> '.join(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the parameter `sep` of the built-in `print` function (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#print)), alongside with the list unpacking operator `*`.
For your case:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print(*my_list, sep=' -> ')
```

Note that I replaced `list` variable name with `my_list`. It is highly recommended to avoid shadowing names, specifically built-in names like `list`.