# How to return a concatenated tuple?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, tuples

I'm working on a python script that would read from a table then send a single message to the users including the column information on each row the query returns, the script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib
import psycopg2


connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                  password="postgres",
                                  host="localhost",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="myDB")
db_cursor = connection.cursor()


s = "SELECT error_message FROM temp.data_upload_errors"
db_cursor.execute(s)
try:
    array_rows = db_cursor.fetchall()
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    t_message = "Postgres Database error: " + e + "/n SQL: " + s
   #return render_template("error.html", t_message = t_message)
db_cursor.close()


sender = 'email@provider.com'
receivers = ['email@provider.com']


for t_item in array_rows:
    msg = "Error Message: " , t_item , "<br>"

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except smtplib.SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'as_string'
```

I'd like to return the whole content under `msg`, not just the `[0]` or `[1]` array item.

I'm new to Python so not sure what may be wrong.

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Comment: msg is a tuple, you can use `join` to make it one string (here delimited by a space): `" ".join(msg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that

```
msg = "Error Message: " , t_item , "<br>"
```

is the same as

```
msg = ("Error Message: " , t_item , "<be>")
```

so your `msg` is effectively a tuple.

On the other hand, you are actually overwriting it each time in the for-loop

```
for t_item in array_rows:
    msg = "Error Message: " , t_item , "<br>"
```

so your `msg` will contain only the last item from the array.

I think what you really need to do is something like this

```
msg = "<br>".join("Error Message: " + " ".join(t_item) for t_item in array_rows)
```

Here `" ".join(t_item)` is a generic way to properly convert each item from the array from `tuple` to `str`. Taking into account your SQL query, you are selecting only 1 column from the table, thus each `t_item` is actually a 1-element tuple so you can just use `t_item[0]` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, If I wanted to send this and get the <br> work, is there any additional step I would need to do?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried wrapping the line into a print statement

e.g.

- `print(smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string()))`

Otherwise you can include all elements using:

- `msg[:]`

Other you can use `"".join(msg)` as well since it's a tuple [if you want it all on one line]