# How do I create a list from a CSV file column?

Tags: python, list, csv

I am fairly new to coding, and I need to put columns from a CSV file into a list. I cannot use any libraries like Pandas. This is the current code I have, but it is taking each character individually. What do I need to change so it takes the entire word?

```
def readfile(f):
    with open(f) as csv_file:
        csv_reader= csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter= ',')
        
        for i in csv_reader:
            newlist= list(i[1])
            print(newlist)
```

This is an example of the output created.

```
['P', 'O', 'P', 'U', 'L', 'A', 'T', 'I', 'O', 'N']
['5', '2', '2', ',', '8', '1', '8']
['1', '5', '5', ',', '6', '5', '6']
['9', '6', '6', ',', '7', '0', '9']
['7', '7', '3', ',', '8', '8', '7']
['8', ',', '4', '4', '7', ',', '6', '0', '9']
['1', '4', ',', '4', '8', '4', ',', '2', '4', '2']
['1', ',', '3', '6', '4', ',', '4', '0', '0']
['1', ',', '1', '7', '1', ',', '0', '2', '7']
['4', ',', '3', '5', '0', ',', '9', '0', '1']
['5', ',', '0', '4', '6', ',', '7', '8', '0']
['4', '0', ',', '6', '0', '1']
['4', '4', ',', '9', '0', '9']
['3', '8', ',', '6', '6', '6']
```

I need it to all be in one list, like `[522,818 , 155,656 , etc]`

Comment: Do not do `list(i[1])`. You convert a string into a list of letters.

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like to concatenate the outputs of all rows into one list? For example, you have two rows (row 1: [1,2]) and (row 2: [3,4]). You want to produce a list containing [1,2,3,4]?

Comment: Post the first 10 lines of your CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would like to concatenate the rows from a csv containing a list in each row, such that an input csv looking like:

```
population
1,2
3,4
```

would print -> `[1,2,3,4]`

You can use the [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) function on the python `list` builtin.
Here's how it would look:

```
import csv
with open('example.csv') as ff:
     reader = csv.reader(ff)
     reader.next() # skip the header that you arent using
     concat_output = []
     for row in reader:
         concat_output.extend(row)
     print(concat_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
>>>''.join(['5', '2', '2', ',', '8', '1', '8'])
'522,818'
```

I just found this earlier thread which provides more background/terminology: [How to concatenate items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string).