# Keep elements with pattern in pandas series without converting them to list

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list, series

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["Air type:1, Space kind:2, water", "something, Space blu:3, somethingelse"], columns = ['A'])
```

and I want to create a new column that contains for each row all the elements that have a ":" in them. So for example in the first row I want to return "type:1, kind:2" and for the second row I want "blu:3". I managed by using a list comprehension in the following way:

```
df['new'] = [[y for y in x  if ":" in y] for x in df['A'].str.split(",")]
```

But my issue is that the new column contains list elements.

```
    A                                                       new
0   Air type:1, Space kind:2, water                         [Air type:1, Space kind:2]
1   something at the start:4, Space blu:3, somethingelse    [something at the start:4, Space blu:3]
```

I have not used Python a lot so I am not 100% whether I am missing a more Pandas specific way to do this. If there is one, more than happy to learn about it and use it.
If this is a correct approach how can I convert the elements back into strings in order to do regexes on them? I tried [How to concatenate items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string) but this is not working as I would like it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) here.

```
df['new'] = df['A'].str.findall('\w+:\w+')

                                 A               new
0            type:1, kind:2, water  [type:1, kind:2]
1  something, blu:3, somethingelse           [blu:3]
```

**EDIT**:

When there are multiple words then try

```
df['new'] = df['A'].str.findall('[^\s,][^:,]+:[^:,]+').str.join(', ')

                                      A                       new
0        Air type:1, Space kind:2, water  Air type:1, Space kind:2
1  something, Space blu:3, somethingelse               Space blu:3
```

Comment: @User2321 Updated the answer. Modified the regex pattern to avoid the extra space but there may be a much better regex pattern than this.

Comment: Thank you. Well based on the problem and the specifications the solution works,
 regex optimization is not a top priority for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findall` with `join`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["type:1, kind:2, water", "something, blu:3, somethingelse"], columns = ['A'])
df['new'] = df['A'].str.findall(r'[^\s:,]+:[^\s,]+').str.join(', ')
df['new']
# => 0    type:1, kind:2
# => 1             blu:3
```

The regex matches

- `[^\s:,]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace, `:` and `,`
- `:` - a colon
- `[^\s,]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `,`.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/SBafep/1).

The `.str.join(', ')` concats all the found matches with `,`+space.

Comment: Thank you! How would you deal with cases where there is more than one word before the :. I have updated my code example (apologies for the confusion I simply forgot to put one of the double word examples there)

Comment: @User2321 Ch3steR built upon my pattern. `r'[^\s:,][^:,]*:[^:,]+'` will do for the time being.

Comment: Well new day, new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981401/python-regex-to-pick-all-elements-that-dont-match-pattern