# Python regex to pick all elements that don't match pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I asked a similar question yesterday [Keep elements with pattern in pandas series without converting them to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64958329/keep-elements-with-pattern-in-pandas-series-without-converting-them-to-list/64959197?noredirect=1#comment114852920_64959197) and now I am faced with the opposite problem.

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["Air type:1, Space kind:2, water, wood", "berries, something at the start:4, Space blu:3, somethingelse"], columns = ['A'])
```

and I want to pick all elements that don't have a ":" in them.
What I tried is the following regex which seems to be working:

```
df['new'] = df.A.str.findall('(^|\s)([^:,]+)(,|$)')
    A                                                               new
0   Air type:1, Space kind:2, water, wood                           [( , water, ,), ( , wood, )]
1   berries, something at the start:4, Space blu:3, somethingelse   [(, berries, ,), ( , somethingelse, )]
```

If I understand this correctly, findall searched for 3 patterns (the ones that I have in parenthesis) and returned as many as it could find in tuples wrapped in a list.
Is there a way to avoid this and simply return only the middle pattern?
As in for the first row: water, wood
for the second row: berries, somethingelse

I also tried the opposite approach:

```
df.A.str.replace('[^\s,][^:,]+:[^:,]+', '').str.replace('\s*,', '')
```

which seems to be working close to what I want (only the commas between the patterns are missing) but I am wondering if I am missing something that would make my life easier.

Comment: Try this: `df.A.str.findall(r'(?:^|,)([^:,]+)(?=,|$)')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex code:

```
>>> df['new'] = df.A.str.findall(r'(?:^|,)([^:,]+)(?=,|$)')
>>> print (df)
                                                   A                        new
0              Air type:1, Space kind:2, water, wood            [ water,  wood]
1  berries, something at the start:4, Space blu:3...  [berries,  somethingelse]
```

Regex used is:

`(?:^|,)`: Match start or comma

- `([^:,]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that is not a `:` and not a `,`
- `(?=,|$)`: Lookahead to assert that we have either a `,` or end of line ahead

Comment: One may also use `df.A.str.findall(r'(?:^|,)([^:,]+)(?=,|$)').apply(','.join)` to get comma delimited list of matched substrings

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex which use non-capturing group `(?:)` :

```
df.A.str.findall(r'(?:^|\s)([^:,]{2,})(?:,|$)')
```

This returns the following output:

```
Name: A, dtype: object
0               [water, wood]
1    [berries, somethingelse]
```

Comment: This is quite good, the only issue is that in my actual data I don't have always two occurrences of the : pattern. Thank you though!

Comment: `[^:,]{2,}` means that you will match only string that have at least 2 consecutive characters that are not `:` or `,`. This will ensure that you don't match string with single letter.

Comment: They are not bad, it is just a complex topic ;-). You're welcome, have a nice day