# Turn a list of items into a string with spaces

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings called `args`. The list looks like this: `['I', 'eat', 'eggs']`

I want to generate a string that is all the items in the list, seperated by spaces. (`"I eat eggs"`)

How can I do this if the list always has a different amount of items?

Comment: I believe this is answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in args])
```

or

`listToStr = ' '.join(args)` by @Jasmijn

Comment: If you know that each item in `args` is already a string, `' '.join(args)` also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
args = ['I', 'eat', 'rice']
myString = ''
for i in args[:-1]:
  myString += i
  myString += " " 
myString += args[-1]  
print(myString)
```