# How to remove a space/whitespace from a string while concatenate operation in Python

Tags: python, removing-whitespace

I have this:

```py
print('abcd'+'_',cariable)
```

which gives me this:

> abcd_  2021_mc.txt

But i need this :  abcd_2021_mc.txt   i.e. no space between _ and 2.

Can anybody suggest me on this. it would be of a great HELP !! thanks in Advance :)

Comment: please have a look at python's fstrings. `print(f"abcd{cariable}")` will give you the result you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable `cariable` is a string then you can do string concatenation directly and just do `print('abcd'+'_'+cariable)`. That should result in `abcd_2021_mc.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the separator used by `print` using the `sep` parameter.

```py
>>> print('abcd','2021_mc.txt', sep='')
abcd2021_mc.txt
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build string using the + operator:

```
a = '_' + '2021'
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you what you want:

```
print('abcd' + '_' + cariable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sep` argument for print function.

```
print("abcd", cariable, sep='_')
```

Comment: Thanks Alot Hook !! that is one of the option that worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are concatenating `'abcd'` and `'_'` when the results are clearly `'abcd_'`.

When you print multiple fields, the default separator is a space. But you can override that. I can only deduce that `cariable` is '2021_mc.txt', so:

```py
print('abcd', '_', cariable, sep='') # no space between 'abcd', '_', and cariable
#or:
print('abcd_', cariable, sep='')
#or:
print('abcd' + '_', cariable, sep='')
```

**Update**

```py
>>> cariable = '2021_mc.txt'
>>> print('abcd', '_', cariable, sep='') # no space between 'abcd', '_', and cariable
abcd_2021_mc.txt
>>> #or:
>>> print('abcd_', cariable, sep='')
abcd_2021_mc.txt
>>> #or:
>>> print('abcd' + '_', cariable, sep='')
abcd_2021_mc.txt
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks BooBoo. Option 1st and 3rd worked for me. :)

Comment: All three should give the same exact results. See updated answer. And I *thought* that the idea was to print *multiple* values with a print statement without intervening spaces and the solution was to specify `sep=''`. Yet you accepted as the *best* answer one that simply avoids printing multiple values altogether and instead just concatenates everything together. I don't get it.

Comment: reason why 2nd option not suitable is because the underscore "_" is not adjoined with the string abcd (modified here) and it cannot be placed along with before concatenate operations. So any way other two worked for me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using f-strings:

```
print(f"abcd_{cariable}")
```

If you need to have "abcd" and "_" separated:

```
s = "abcd"
print(f"{s}_{cariable}")
```