# How to convert List to String in Python

Tags: python, string, list

```
paid_modules = data[(arrs[1])]["paid_modules"]

  for key_modules in paid_modules:
    list(key_modules_ids)
    if key_modules == "PESQUISA":
      key_modules_ids.append(59)
    if key_modules == "OBJETIVOS":
      key_modules_ids.append(54)
    if key_modules == "AVALIACAO":
      key_modules_ids.append(53)
  
  print("modulos",key_modules_ids)
```

I'm doing a code who needs to print numbers like a string format, now it's printing like a list, this way: ***[53,54,59]***.

What a need is print like a string, for example: ***'53,54,59'***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
print("modulos",','.join( str(i) for i in key_modules_ids) )
```

Comment: You need `str(i)` since `join` accepts a list of strings, not ints