# How to separate strings multiplied by integer in Python?

Tags: python, string

Let's say we have a text "Welcome to India". And I want to multiply this string with 3, but to appear with comma delimitation, like "Welcome to India, Welcome to India, Welcome to India". The thing is I know this piece of code could work:

```
a = 'Welcome to India'

required = a * 3 # but this code is not comma-delimited.
```

Also, this piece of code doesn't work as well

```
required = (a + ", ") * 3 # because it puts comma even at the end of the string
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to following tags you have used: `pandas`, `dataframe`?

Comment: we have string texts in each row of a dataframe. But the methods didn't seem to work on rows of a dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Answer (score 3):

```
", ".join(["Welcome to India"]*3)
```

Comment: Yes, and in your case, `required = ", ".join([a]*3)`.

Comment: But what do we do in case of having a dataframe? There it won't work

Comment: Then you're not asking your question well. You're asking for strings, not dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the part of your code that you say doesn't work well because it adds a comma to the end, you can modify it like this:

```
required = (a + ", ") * 2 + a
```

Or if you don't like it, you can use sum instead of multiply, it's not the optimal way, for sure, but it will work:

```
a = 'Welcome to India'
required = a + ", " + a + ", " + a
```

Answer (score 0):

Define Function and you can use it.

```
def commaFunc(value, count):
    buffer = []
    for x in range(count):
        buffer[x] = value
    return ",".join(buffer)
```