# How do i make an list of characters into a string?

Tags: python-3.x

#the list to make an string format
a = ['h','e','l','l','o','','w','o','r','l','d','!']

#wanted output

> > > hello world!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Comment: See: [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score -1):

It seems some suggestions was given above about how to solve this problem. An approach that can be taken though is creating a empty string variable and concatenating all the characters from the given character list to the string variable. For example,

```
a = ['h','e','l','l','o','','w','o','r','l','d','!']
temp_string = ""
for eachChar in a:
    temp_string += eachChar
print(temp_string)
```

The output of this result to

```
helloworld!
```

This is due to the null character between hello and world. If the null character was instead a space such as ['h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','!'], the output will result to what you have displayed above.