# How to convert multiple string in one list python

Tags: python, string, list, types

I am wondering how to convert multiple string in a list into one string in a list?

It will be like this:

```
input:["a", "b", "c"]
output:["a,b,c"]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate (join) items in a list to a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs thank for link, I saw this post, but it will be output a string not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join()

```
string = ["a", "b", "c"]
[','.join(string)] #if you want to return it inside a list otherwise
','.join(string)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my_string = ["a", "b", "c"]
new_string = []
for s in my_string:
    new_string.append(s)

print (new_string)
```

output
['a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: this just copies over one list to another list, and is a rather inefficient way to do that. I don't see the point in doing that.