# Convert a multiple elements list to a single element list

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
my_list = ["h", "e", "l", "l", o"]
```

What I would like to have is:

```
 new_list = ["hello"]
```

Comment: `["".join(my_list)]`

Comment: Did you do _any_ research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate (join) items in a list to a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]

result = ''.join(my_list)
my_list.clear()
my_list.append(result)
print(my_list)
```

This will output the result:

```
['hello']
```