# Hi, New to coding and cant seem to find the solution for this error (Python)

Tags: python, syntax, new-operator

[image]

```
text = ["this","is","text"]
print(f"hello and {text, end=","}")
```

```
Input In [58]
    print(f"hello and {text, end=","}")
                                  ^
SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}'
```

I am trying to remove brackets and commas while using an f string

........................

Comment: It stopped giving me an error message, however the issue of the commas and brackets remain.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate (join) items in a list to a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are trying to print the contents of the list after the hardcoded string. So your code is first printing "hello and" and then the string representation of the list 'text'. In order to print the elements of the list using an f string you can do:

```
text = ['this','is','text']
print(f"hello and {' '.join(text)}")
```