# How to print nested list into charter side by side in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python

```python
a = [['z', 'G', 'j', 'E', 'U'], ['%', '#', '(', '!', ')'], ['6', '4', '8', '1', '3']]
```

I want to print above nested list into character which are side by side
example output:

```
zGjEU%#(!)64813
```

How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate (join) items in a list to a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It will be easier to help you if you give it your best shot first! :^)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a [nested comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) along with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> a = [['z', 'G', 'j', 'E', 'U'], ['%', '#', '(', '!', ')'], ['6', '4', '8', '1', '3']]
>>> print(''.join(c for chars in a for c in chars))
zGjEU%#(!)64813
```

Comment: For the golfers `print(''.join(map(''.join, a))`

Comment: can you explain me this command ''.join(c for chars in a for c in chars).  I am beginner in python

Comment: Consider clicking on the link and reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [['z', 'G', 'j', 'E', 'U'], ['%', '#', '(', '!', ')'], ['6', '4', '8', '1', '3']]
result = ""
for item in a:
    for char in item:
        result += char
```

result:

```
'zGjEU%#(!)64813'
```