# I'm trying make a list into a string in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I change  the list into a string but it is not printing on the same line

```
spam= ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
for i in spam:
    print(str(i))
```

Comment: This isn't really turning it into a string, but `print`ing the individual elements. That being said, `print(i, end=' ')` seems to be what you're after. Or simply, `print(' '.join(spam))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate (join) items in a list to a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Comment: `str(spam)` perhaps?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Since you are printing each item in the list individually using the for loop, they wont print in the same line. To print them on the same line do the following instead of using a loop:

```
spam= ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

print (', '.join(spam))
```

Output:

```
apples, bananas, tofu, cats
```

You can optionally set a single space to show them separately like the following.

```
print(' '.join(spam))
```

Output:

```
apples bananas tofu cats
```