# How to convert a list inside of a class to a string in Python in order to be able to write it a txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a class which contains an empty list, static and instance methods. When I add new instances which contain strings to this class, they get appended to this empty list and everything is working correctly. I'm trying to write a function that will get this list and write it in a txt file but instead of the actual content, I'm getting something like this when I try the map() function:

`"0x000001E6B9C718D0><Products.Product"`

And if I type a simple .join and convert the list to a string, it's showing me this error:

> "The Python "TypeError: can only join an iterable"

which tells me the list is not being properly converted to a string.

I've looked online extensively for the past 2 hours but so far nothing. None of the solutions have fixed my problem. Probably because this list is inside a class and instances are getting appended to it but I don't know.

EDIT: Forgot the code here it is:

```
class Product:
#This class is for adding products.

products = []
def __init__(self, name, serial_number, price):
    self.name = name
    self.serial_number = serial_number
    self.price = price

#Instance method to show the information about an instance.
def show(self):
    print("Product's Name:", self.name, "|", "Serial Number:", self.serial_number, "|", "Price:", self.price)

#Class method to add a product to the product's list.
@staticmethod
def add_product(product):
    Product.products.append(product)

#Class method to show the info of all products
@staticmethod
def show_products():
   for product in Product.products:
       product.show()

#Class method to write th items in a txt file:
@staticmethod
def write_list():
    file = open("Products.txt", "a")
    file.write(''.join(str(Product.products)))
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code?

Comment: Are you calling `join` with the class object or the list? Please [edit] and create a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate (join) items in a list to a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to concatenate a list of instances to a string. When you use `join` to concatenate the list, it throws an error because it expects an iterable of `string`s.

You can simply convert each instance to a `string` and then write to your file.
Something like this;

```py
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(str(p) for p in Product.products_list))
```

**Edit** Modified function in given code example

```py
@staticmethod
def write_list():
    with open("Products.txt", "w") as file:
        for product in Product.products:
            file.write(product.name + ',' + product.serial_number + ',' + str(product.price) + '\n')
```

The issue is that function is currently writing the Product.products list directly to the file without properly formatting the contents. As a result, you're seeing the memory address of each instance instead of the actual data.

Comment: It didn't work. Here's the code that I wrote:

Comment: @staticmethod
    def write_list():
        file = open("Products.txt", "a")
        file.write('\n'.join(str(p) for p in Product.products))

Comment: and here's the result inside the txt file:<Products.Product object at 0x00000204B74A1410>
<Products.Product object at 0x00000204B74A1250>
<Products.Product object at 0x00000204B74A1450>
<Products.Product object at 0x00000204B74A14D0>
<Products.Product object at 0x00000204B74A1490>
<Products.Product object at 0x00000204B74C0F50>

Comment: @SaintDev The `Product` class should implement the [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) function.

Comment: @SaintDev, as Johnny Mop said, but even then I've provided an edit that'll suit your needs

Comment: @RaghavKukreti it finally worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to serialize the class instead with [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Converting a class to a string yourself is a bad idea, you should let the standard library do it for you instead. `pickle` serializes into binary, you likely want to encode that. binary in base64 to make it look like regular text. Like this:

```
import base64
import pickle


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, lst=[]):
        self.lst = lst

    def add(self, val):
        self.lst.append(val)


myObj = MyClass([1])
myObj.add(2)

s = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(myObj)).decode('utf-8')
print(s)  # => gASVLQAAAAAAAACMCF9fbWFpbl9flIwHTXlDbGFzc5STlCmBlH2UjANsc3SUXZQoSwFLAmVzYi4=
```

You can then read it the string back from the file and decode it:

```
import base64
import pickle


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, lst=[]):
        self.lst = lst

    def add(self, val):
        self.lst.append(val)
        

s = "gASVLQAAAAAAAACMCF9fbWFpbl9flIwHTXlDbGFzc5STlCmBlH2UjANsc3SUXZQoSwFLAmVzYi4="
obj = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(s))
print(obj.lst)  # => [1, 2]
```