# For loop in a single line and assign it to a variable in Python

Tags: python

I need to assign a result of for loop to a variable. It is easy to print the for loop in a single line using `end =" "`, but I am unable to assign the result as a single line.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(4):
    print(a[i], end =" ")
```

Result is `1 2 3 4`

But I have to assign the result to a variable as `var = 1234`.

I am trying below way which is incorrect and not providing the result:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(4):
    var = print(a[i], end =" ")
    print(var) # It provides the result in multiple line
```

What can I try next?

Comment: in this case is `var` an integer?

Comment: `print` always returns `None` so assigning the result of `print` to `var` is one problem.

Comment: @GIZ maybe smt like this `var = [a[i], print(a[i], end=' ')][0]`

Comment: @cards Syntax error aside, I'm not sure what you think that is supposed to accomplish. `print` does not produce usable data; it only returns `None` after writing to a file.

Comment: Do you want the integer `1234` or the string `'1234'` as the result?

Comment: @chepner the code works without syntax error

Comment: @cards You changed it since I made that comment. But the call to `print` has no effect on your assignment to `var`. You create the list `[a[i], None]`, then just assign `a[i]` to `var`.

Comment: I am downvoting because this question lacks clarity. The _question_ is about assigning variables in a for loop, but the the _answer_ the OP seems to be seeking is more about how to print a list of ints as a single concatenated value. It's also a somewhat common problem that has been answered many times (if you ask the right question - how to concatenate a list of ints). For example: [how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Answer (score 0):

Use join to achieve this when a is a list of numbers

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var = ''.join(str(num) for num in a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the join() method to concatenate the elements of the list as a string and then assign the string to the variable.

**For Example :**

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var = ''.join(str(i) for i in a)
print(var) # Output: '1234'
```

Other way to do this is :

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var = ''.join(map(str, a))
print(var) # Output: '1234'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension along with the `join()` function to achieve this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var = ''.join([str(i) for i in a])
print(var)  # Output: 1234
```