# python script: Arrange text file one word in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have a `.txt` file that is not arranged properly and contains 11273 characters in one line  I would like to arrange one character in one line and I am unable to do so because there is no space between characters. `가` is one character and I want to arrange the `.txt` file like the output

**Input (.txt file)**

```
ABCD
```

**Output (.txt file)**

```
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate (join) items in a list to a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string) Specifically see [Wallebot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37227532/14991864)

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a trivially easy problem.

Comment: `fold -w1 input.txt`

Comment: @tshiono not working it shows ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("input.txt") as input, open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write("\n".join(input.read()))
```

Comment: You don't even need the `.split("")`, strings are iterable and hence a valid argument for `join`.

Comment: SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xec' in file /media/cvpr/CM_22/doctr/missing_Characters.py on line 47, but no encoding declared; see https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: @KhawarIslam That is a separate question (which is also a duplicate), your file isn't using UTF-8 encoding. See: [SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x91'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092176/syntaxerror-non-utf-8-code-starting-with-x91)

Comment: my text is Korean based but I can not write in StackOverflow they consider as a SPAM