# Converting array of Integers to String in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

Can someone please help me with below request.
I am trying to convert the below output from sql in Python and use as string

```
Value=[(132,), (2434,), (233434,), (56644,), (3435,), ]

Output:
Value=132,2434,233434,56644,3435

tried to convert print(str(value[0][0]))


Expecting : Value=132,2434,233434,56644,3435
```

Comment: Why do you expect that code to give that output? You've only accessed the first element of the first tuple in your `value` list. Why do you expect it to somehow print the elements from the other tuples too?

Comment: That is not an array of integers, but a list of tuples.

Comment: `Value=132,2434,233434,56644,3435` is not a string. it isn't clear exactly what you want.

Comment: I think this answers your question: [How to concatenate (join) items in a list to a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Expecting : Value="132,2434,233434,56644,3435"

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to get string output from a list of tuples:

```
values = [(132,), (2434,), (233434,), (56644,), (3435,)]
output_values = ",".join([str(i) for element in values for i in element])
print(output_values)
```

**Output**:

```
132,2434,233434,56644,3435
```

**Explanation**:

I traversed each tuple as `element` and converted each value of the tuple to string and joined them using `,`.