# __str__ outputs "instance at 0x00E4F558"

Tags: python, string

This is my first cry for help in this site. I have searched for an answer here, but nothing really clears it for me.

I'm trying to learn Python.  I've in the "class" chapter.
The following code:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, initial_health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = initial_health
        self.inventory = []

    def __str__(self):
        s  = "Name: " + self.name
        s += "| Health: " + str(self.health)
        s += "| Inventory: " + str(self.inventory)
        return s

    def grab(self, item):
        self.inventory.append(item)

me = Character("vic", 37)
me.grab("pencil")
me.grab("paper")
print str(me)
```

...produces:

```
Name: vic| Health: 37| Inventory: ['pencil', 'paper']
```

But the following code, which appears to me pretty similar, prints out the memory locations rather than the variables themselves:

```
import random
SUITS = ['C', 'S', 'H', 'D']
RANKS = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
VALUES = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10}

# define card class
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        if (suit in SUITS) and (rank in RANKS):
            self.suit = suit
            self.rank = rank
            self.value = self.get_value()
        else:
            print "Invalid card: " + str(suit) + str(rank)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.suit) + str(self.rank)
    def get_cardDetails(self):
        return self.suit + self.rank + ": " + str(self.value)
    def get_suit(self):
        return self.suit
    def get_rank(self):
        return self.rank
    def get_value(self):
        value = VALUES[self.rank]
        return value

class Hand:
    def __init__(self, card1, card2):
        self.cardCount = 0
        self.cards = []
        self.cards.append(card1)
        self.cardCount += 1
        self.cards.append(card2)
        self.cardCount += 1
        self.value = self.get_value()
        print "Dealed hand: " + str(self.cards[0]) + str(self.cards[1])
        print "Dealed hand: " + str(self.cards)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.cards)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cards)
    def get_details(self):
        print "Hand: "
        for each in self.cards:
            print " -" + str(each) + ": " + str(each.value)
        s = "Cards: " + str(self.cardCount) + \
               " | Hand: " + str(self.cards) + \
               " | Total Value: " + str(self.value) + " |"
        return s
    def add_card(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)
        self.cardCount += 1
        self.value = self.get_value()
        print "Added: " + str(card)
    def get_value(self):
        value = 0
        for each in self.cards:
            value = value + each.value
        return value


c1 = Card("C", "2")
c2 = Card("C", "3")
h = Hand(c1, c2)
print str(h)
```

Output:

```
Dealed hand: C2C3
Dealed hand: [<__main__.Card instance at 0x00E4F558>, <__main__.Card instance at 0x00E543C8>]
[<__main__.Card instance at 0x00E4F558>, <__main__.Card instance at 0x00E543C8>]
```

I'm sure I must be missing something here -I'm just learning this after all.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.  And sorry for the long post.

Comment: This is the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` - see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python - specifically the 'Container’s `__str__` uses contained objects’ `__repr__`' discussion.

Comment: More importantly, the `str` of a sequence prints the `repr` of each of its elements. There are a number of questions on this; I'll find one and link to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joining a list of python objects with \_\_str\_\_ method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588685/joining-a-list-of-python-objects-with-str-method)

Answer (score 6):

The `__str__` method of a list calls `__repr__` on the elements of the list, not `__str__`. You can either iterate through the list casting the elements to str yourself, or write a Hand class which subclasses from list and defines `__str__` to call `__str__` on its elements.

Comment: I modified the __str__ method as follows (this is my interpretation of your suggestion)
    `def __str__(self):
        c = []
        for each in self.cards:
            c.append(str(each))
        return str(c)`
Calling the str method now prints the list!  I think that's what I wanted...  Thank you!!

Comment: @vic That still may not do quite what you want, because you've now called str on a list of strings, which will give you the __repr__ of those strings! Try `def __str__(self): return "[{0}]".format(", ".join(str(item) for item in self.cards))` But if that way is working for you then go with it!

Comment: Ahh... I see what you are saying.  Now the output is the string representation of a list, like "["item1", "item2", ...]", instead of ["item1", "item2", ...] -I'll try the __repr__ bit.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

That depends what you are trying to print. In Python if you are printing an object `a` it is first converted to string by evaluating `a.__str__()`. If your class has a method `__str__` defined, Python uses it. Otherwise it uses the `__str__` method from `object` (in new style classes and in Python 3.x).

Anyway the way the objects are printed depends on how the `__str__` method is implemented.
If you are evaluating `str(els)`, where `els` is a list, then Python actually calls `List.__str__(lis)` and this function is implemented in such a way that it prints `repr` of objects contained inside. (And function `repr` returns by default such output as you see.)

If you want to use the objects `str` methods, you can write:

```
[str(el) for el in els]
```

where `els` is a list of your objects.

Answer (score 1):

Lists print the `repr()` of their elements, not the `str()`. Add:

```
__repr__ = __str__
```

to your `Card` class definition. This will make the `repr()` of your `Card` class the same as the `str()` of it, and lists will print your cards as you expect.

You could instead write the `__str__` of `Hand` to take the `str()` rather than the `repr()` of list items.