# Returning individual string representation of all objects in list of objects

Tags: python, class, oop

**Is it possible to return the string representation (using __str__) of all objects in a list of objects from a different classes own __str__ function?**

Say I have a class that contains all methods being performed on Bar objects. Call this class Foo. Then:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bars = []  # contains Bar objects

    def __str__(self):
        return "This is the Foo object"

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1

    def __str__(self):
        return "This is Bar object: " + arg1

def main():
    foo = Foo()
    print(str(foo))
```

I want to print the string representation of all of the objects in self.bars **WHEN** I call main(), since creating an instance of the Bar object would not give me access to the string representation of all of the objects in self.bars.

To clarify, I am not asking the same question as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558474/how-to-apply-str-function-when-printing-a-list-of-objects-in-python) post relating to the need of **__repr__**. Instead, I want to return each object's string representation individually, as with a for loop.

Is there anyway to do this, reasonably or unreasonably?

Comment: Do you mean something like `return ','.join(str(b) for b in self.bars)`?

Comment: Also, if I AM asking the same question as the link I posted, then feel free to correct me. If this is a duplicate in some sense of the word, then it is just because of my misunderstanding of the subject matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already said how to do this, use a for loop.

```
return "".join([str(x) + "\n" for x in self.bars])
```

Comment: You can't return a `list` from `__str__`.  Perhaps `'\n'.join(map(str, self.bars))` or the list-comprehension equivalent...

Comment: @Natecat The real problem here seems to be that __str__ cannot return a list, or a tuple. In this case, attempting multiple elements such as `return ("This is the Foo object", ".join([str(x) + "\n" for x in self.bars]))` does not work, as it returns a tuple. Unless I'm mistaken, in Python all functions that return multiple elements return as a tuple and must be unzipped? It should be easy to edit the return statement to work, but this might not work in all cases.