# Self Object of python

Tags: python, list, loops, class, self

My code:

```
class Sentence():

    def __init__(self, cells, count):
        self.cells = set(cells)
        self.count = count

class Mines():
      
   def __init__(self):
       
       self.knowledge = []

   def add_knowledge(self, cells, count):
       
        # let count=8
        # let cells=(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)..........    
       for i in range(count):
          sen=Sentence(cells, count)
          self.knowledge.append(sen)

          print(self.knowledge)
```

first of all I have created object of Sentence class then i am appending this in the list.
then I want to print self.knowledge in loop.
actually I want to print whole list (knowledge) in loop but i am not able to print the list.
it gives me output like <mines.Sentence object at 0x00000000042D8748>
can anybody help me how i print whole self.knowledge object.

Comment: Why do you think that's wrong? The elements of the list are `Sentence` objects, and that's what `<mines.Sentence ...>` is.

Comment: What is the purpose of creating `Sentence` objects each time with the *same* `cells` list? What is that useful for? What do you expect as output? Can you provide the driver code that actually calls this function?

Comment: You probably want `cells[i]`.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: If you want to change how `Sentence` objects are shown in the list, define its `__repr__` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply \_\_str\_\_ function when printing a list of objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558474/how-to-apply-str-function-when-printing-a-list-of-objects-in-python)

Comment: What is the purpose of `count`? If it's the count of values in `cells` then don't pass the count around. Just use `len(cells)` as needed. Especially since your `self.count = count` code can persist the wrong number of cells (because you stored them in a set which will remove duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned up here, if you want to show object properties, you will have to create (overwrite) a method called `__repr__` in the first object:

This is an example of an output:

```
class Sentence():

    def __init__(self, cells, count):
        self.cells = set(cells)
        self.count = count

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'self.cells: {self.cells} self.count: {self.count}'
    
class Mines():
      
   def __init__(self):
       
       self.knowledge = []

   def add_knowledge(self, cells, count):
       
        # let count=8
        # let cells=(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)..........    
       for i in range(count):
          sen=Sentence(cells, count)
          self.knowledge.append(sen)

       print(self.knowledge)



a=Mines()
count = 3
cells = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)]


a.add_knowledge(cells, count)
```

outputs:
`[self.cells: {(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)} self.count: 3, self.cells: {(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)} self.count: 3, self.cells: {(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)} self.count: 3]`

Comment: no problem, hope it helps